# Network tab shows that during the loading of the page, nothing happens between 40ms and 120ms but then it keeps loading content

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Can someone explain to me why is there 80ms of idle time in the middle of the page load? Is this meant to happen and why are my GET requests for the JSON files not happening during that time?

[image]

Comment: Use the [devtools performance profiler](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference) to see what's happening there.